# What's the real life purpose of Knuth arrows?

Tags: combinatorics, notation, recursion, applications, number-systems

I recently read about [Knuth's Arrows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation). Didn't even know those operations existed. My questions is: Do they have real-life applications? Most of the times a mathematical development follows a real-life need (or another science need). What's the originating need to conceive these hyperexponential operations?

**Edit**: By *REAL LIFE (or another science) NEED* I mean a need which derives from a real-life application (e.g. say integration originated from trying to guess circle area, and derivatives solve many economics/physics problems, while simple polynomials have several applications including odds and computer science...), either directly or indirectly wrt solving the need.

Comment: The *quintessential* MASSIVE number is *Graham's Number* which occurs in mathematics as an upper bound to a problem in Ramsey Theory. The number is difficult to express even in arrow notation.

Comment: You may safely forget about them. In any case, if you don't, mathematics surely will.

Comment: There probably needs to be a definition of "real-life need" here. To a mathematician, trying to describe Graham's Number is a real-life need.

Comment: Maybe this is more suitable for a computer science audience, but it seems to me that they are sometimes used to show that some problem is (algorithmically) decidable. Once you know that, there is at least some hope to search for a feasible implementation. (By the way, I disagree with your comments on origins of derivatives and polynomials, but that's another story.)

Comment: @Axoren: On the other hand, Graham's number is only defined the way it is because the uparrow notation happened to be available. Graham made it up on the spot while talking to Martin Gardner; the _actual_ upper bound he had proved was somewhat smaller and defined in a quite different way.

Comment: @Axoren I clarified what do I mean with REAL LIFE.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Interesting, I didn't know that.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli In that case, Peter Franek's comment can be promoted to an answer because he provides an example in which the notation is used *constructively* in the computer science field.

Comment: Speaking as a computer scientist, I have to say that @PeterFranek's suggestion doesn't really ring a bell. Knuth is a computer scientist, of course, but that doesn't mean that everything he has done has immediate applications in CS.

Comment: @PeterFranek Did Luis bring up derivatives and polynomials elsewhere, or are you just providing what you believe is a counterexample to his remark in this question?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein That was a reaction to "e.g. say integration and derivatives originated from trying to guess circle area and economics/physics problems." I think that they originated from Newton's work to explain Kepler law's and the "applications" in economics are almost always artificial.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein By referring to derivatives and polynomials I used them as examples of stuff having applications in real life. I will fix the comment there since it is a bit wrong but anyway I wanted to state what I meant with REAL LIFE application.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Hyper operators in general are proven to be primitive recursive, constructed from lower order hyper operators. Constructing functions from composition of hyper operators and other primitive recursive functions means that the full composition is primitive recursive. Primitive recursive functions that totally computable functions which will always halt. This is what he was alluding to.

Comment: Fixed the "real life" clarification

Comment: Yep. The comment from @PeterFranek works for me. By putting it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Axoren: Yes, but that doesn't really seem to add up to an _application_ of the hyper operators. One could say that the function $$ n \mapsto 3 \mathbin{\underbrace{\uparrow\cdots\uparrow}_n} 3 $$ is _not_ primitive recursive, thereby proving that total computable functions need not be primitive recursive, but the function usually used for that purpose is Ackermann's function, which is similar to -- but not identical to! -- something that can be written with uparrows.

Comment: Sorry, it appears my reading comprehension needs work. I didn't notice any remark about derivatives and polynomials the first time I read the addendum.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein perhaps it was bc you did not update the question edition. Not about comprehension, but about UI update.

Comment: @PeterFranek I repeat: I will accept ur comment as an answer if you post it as answer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That function is not constructed through composition strictly with primitive recursive operations and is totally computable, but that doesn't change what I've said. I said nothing in the way of primitive recursive functions being the only way to construct totally computable functions. However, if you can formulate the solution to an existing problem in terms of hyper operators and primitive recursion, the total computability of that solution is a given from it's construction.

Comment: @Axoren: That is all true. None of it points me toward any practical problem where your observation is helpful. You could say the same about _any_ function that you know how to compute -- simply because you can prove it is comptable does not magically make a real-world problem where it is _important_ that this particular function is computable appear.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Actually, I take that back, I think that function you gave is indeed primitive recursive. You can get the program code of the $n$-th hyper operator through primitive recursion and then apply $\phi(3, 3, p_n)$ where $p_n$ is that program code.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't immediately see your logic there, but I'll think on it. This isn't the place to continue the tangent conversation. Back on topic, outside of theoretic computability, I've only seen one practical application of tetration and only for $x \uparrow 2 = x^x$, and not even for that function itself but it's inverse. One such application of it is in this paper [here](http://eretrandre.org/rb/files/JayFantini1998_203.pdf)

Comment: @Axoren: Is your $\phi$ there some kind of evaluate-this-program function? That is definitely not itself primitive recursive, even when the programming language is restricted to definitions by primitive recursion.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Thanks, I appreciate it, but I don't know much about it, cannot provide reasonable examples so I don't dare to post it as an answer. Take it just as a hint for further searching :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Knuth arrow notation is for expressing primitive recursive functions at a specific level of the hierarchy of such functions. Level is the depth of nested FOR loops needed to compute the function.

The most frequent (but still quite uncommon) use of the notation would be to graphically display how inefficient a particular upper bound argument is in a combinatorial proof.  The numbers connected to Graham's paper with "Graham's number" are an example.  The actual value of the quantity bounded in the paper is probably much smaller, like $13$ or $20$.

I have never heard of a genuine *lower* bound like $n \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow n$ (something larger than a tower of $n$ exponentials, but still primitive recursive) appearing in a combinatorial problem.  If it did, it would mean that something like Knuth notation is unavoidable when considering that problem.

There are natural problems in computer science where functions beyond the primitive recursive hierarchy can appear, but strictly speaking these are not covered by the Knuth notation.  If you allow extensions like $a \uparrow \cdots \uparrow b$ where the number of arrows is a variable quantity $n$ then Ackermann-like functions can be encoded.  Conway's generalization of the Knuth arrows includes that.

Comment: Counts as "real life (or other science)" to me, since it has an application which has, somehow, relation to a direct usage.